# Фоновая картинка поверх изображения, накладываемого hover

Tags: html, css

Для ссылки пункта-меню задана фоновая картинка

```
<div id="nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="" class="item1">Каталог изображений</a></li>
             </ul>
        </div>​
```

при наведении мышки задано, что сверху накладывается другая картинка, и она перекрывает ту картинку, что задана бэкграундом http://jsfiddle.net/y8AJF/7/ . Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы фоновая картинка пункта меню оставалась поверх того изображения, что накладывается hover'ом? Вносить изображение в теге img в ссылку не хотелось бы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почитайте про множественный background.

Можно тут http://habrahabr.ru/company/microsoft/blog/137705/ или тут http://htmlbook.ru/css/background-position

И поэксперериментируйте...

Или поменяйте условие

```
#nav ul  li:hover {
    background: url('http://static.diary.ru/userdir/2/0/0/4/2004853/76652854.png') no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: нет, это не то, вы путаете.

Comment: Вот так работает, правда не знаю насколько данный пример правилен, т.к. не особо являюсь знатоком CSS.

    #nav ul  li:hover {
    background: url('http://static.diary.ru/userdir/2/0/0/4/2004853/76652854.png') no-repeat;
    width: 116px;
    height: 155px;
}

    #nav ul li a:hover {
        color: #ffffff;    
    }

Comment: Уберите, к черту, ширину и высоту (да и color тоже)

Comment: evlanoff, большое вам спасибо, всё работает)))   
istem, ширину действительно можно убрать, а вот высоту придется оставить, так как высота накладываемой ховером картинки больше, чем высота блока навигации. color нужен для изменения цвета текста.

Comment: Высота, у элемента с селектором :hover - это уже слишком... (используйте отрицательный margin лучше)

Answer (score 0):

в CSS есть такое свойство:
z-index: [значение] 
отображает последовательность отображения элементов.

Comment: нет, здесь не про это речь)

Answer (score 0):

Несколько background можно указывать через запятую вот так:

```
url('http://static.diary.ru/userdir/2/0/0/4/2004853/76652822.png') top center no-repeat, url('http://static.diary.ru/userdir/2/0/0/4/2004853/76652854.png')  no-repeat;
```

```css
#nav ul {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 999;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-left: 130px;
}
    
#nav ul  li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 116px;
}

#nav ul  li a {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 116px;
    height: 145px;
    padding-top: 90px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #5c5c5c;
}

#nav ul  li a.item1 {
    background: url('http://static.diary.ru/userdir/2/0/0/4/2004853/76652822.png') top center no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9999;
}

#nav ul  li a:hover {
    background: 
    url('http://static.diary.ru/userdir/2/0/0/4/2004853/76652822.png') top center no-repeat, url('http://static.diary.ru/userdir/2/0/0/4/2004853/76652854.png')  no-repeat;
    width: 116px;
    height: 145px;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="" class="item1">Каталог изображений</a></li>
         </ul>
    </div>
```